# Valid architectures issue on running iOS apps in ARM macOS

Tags: ios, macos, x86, arm, intel

Apple has announced that ARM version of macOS will support to run iOS apps since WWDC 2020, I know the standard architecture for iOS apps is ARM serials including `arm64`, `arm64e`, `armv7` and `armv7s`, so what apple needs to do is to make compatible between existing binary architectures and new macOS ARM version, this may/should not be a big project, the differences between x86 and ARM should be the more difficult challenge to do.

Here is question, why doesn't apple guide iOS developers to build new apps with more architectures which including `i386` and `x86_64` when uploading app binary to app store? then these new binaries will support existing Intel macOS without big challenges? All users will happy for this.

[image]

Please don't close this as off-topic or related, I really want to know the reason in technically. Secondly in market policy, maybe, if there are.

Comment: In a sense you can already build x86 x86-64 app that run on the x86 x86-64 iOS Simulator(s). Apple didn't bother allowing to distribute them though AppStore though. And probably didn't invest time in a seamless UIKit-x86-64-Simulator-bridge for MacOS neither.

Comment: I prefer believing they won't do that just because arm version of macbook now.